# Largest Power of $11$ that can divide $^{2n}C_n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

I need help answering this question.

If $f(n) =$ the greatest integer $k$ for which $11^k$ divides
$\binom{2n}{n}$, what is the maximum value of $f(n)$ for all integers $1 \le n \le 10000$?
$${2n \choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

I have figured out that $2$ is the greatest power of $11$ which divides $\binom{10000}{5000}$. I don't know how to show that this is/isn't the greatest value that $f(n)$ can take on for $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: How did you get that 2 is the largest power of 11 dividing 10000C5000?

Comment: Check f(7321). If I'm calculating it correctly, it's more than 2.

Comment: It think it should be $3=

Comment: Well, I think f(7321) is 4.

Comment: I used the floor function. If you take the floor of 10000 divided by each power of 11 (11,121,1331), and add the three terms you will get 998. Similarly, with 5000 we get 498. 998-2(498)=2.

Comment: Ok, but n is the smaller number in the binomial coefficient. Shouldn't you be looking at 20000 and 10000? Either way, the max isn't attained there, because f(10000) is only 3, and f(7321) is more than that.

Comment: I chose 7321 because its double is just over a power of 11 namely 11^4.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. So the 2n term has more multiples of 11 than n. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), you are looking for the $n$ which has maximum carries when added to itself in base $11$.  Now $n \leqslant 10000_{10} = 7571_{11}$ and it seems clear we cannot get more than $4$ carries, which is possible say when $n = 6666_{11} = 8784_{10}$.

--
For a check, note $11^4 = 14641 \mid \binom{2 \cdot 8784}{8784}$

Comment: That only yields 3. There are other numbers which yield 4.

Comment: @shrindle Really - did you check?  $6666_{11}$ will obviously have $4$ carries when added to itself.  Alternately, $11^4 | \binom{2\cdot 8784}{8784}$

Comment: My apologies, I did my math wrong. You are correct. Thank you!

Comment: No worries - the numbers are large. Checking carries however is MUCH easier even if you want to generate more examples.